# Does Salesforce Analytics allow reporting on Custom Objects and External Data?

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

I am required to find out some information and I am struggling a little with the information available online.  Are the following assumptions correct?

1. External Data can be imported into Salesforce Analytics(Wave) for use in reporting/dashboards etc (I read a little regarding the API).
2. Custom Object data can be used to generate the eye-pleasing reports they show in the demo's?  These objects are linked to the accounts/contact standard objects but NOT the sales pipeline objects (lead/campaigns etc etc).

If we can use external data and custom objects to build the reports - we are likely to try wave out.

thanks.

Comment: Please define Salesforce Analytics. Do you mean built-in reports, or do you mean the product formerly known as Wave (now known as Einstein Analytics)?

Comment: This was a while ago but at the time it was he product known as Wave (now Einstein). It was deemed too expensive so we haven’t gone down that route. Instead we use Power BI from Microsoft to pull data from salesforce and generate dashboards.

Answer (score 2):

Both Assumptions are correct.

Following connections are possible with Wave to import data in Salesforce :

[image]

Regarding point #2, We tried linked custom object with Account but still not able to see those object in Analytics data set. So, this point needs to be confirmed practically. Demo videos show custom object are supported.

Comment: Thanks, just wish we could trial it.  Have you seen this,http://www.odata.org/blog/salesforce-external-object-integration-using-lightning-connect-with-odata/ included in winter 15.  I expect we will need confirmation on point 2 from salesforce before purchasing, most of our data will be in custom objects :(

Answer (score -1):

Just went through another demo on Wave with our AE last week. Any data that you want to report on must live inside of Salesforce. So, as long as you are importing that data (via ETL or some other means) it can be reported on.

Wave does not currently support reporting on custom objects. Only a select few of the standard objects are currently available for reporting.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_limitations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I maybe answering part 1 with this, but have you read/seen this:   http://www.odata.org/blog/salesforce-external-object-integration-using-lightning-connect-with-odata/ also, thanks for the custom object info

Comment: Hi All, unless I am reading this conversation incorrectly - Custom Objects are completely supported.. and can be used by the on platform ELT tool. There is a nuance on some managed packages, where you have to apply the license for the managed package to the integration user - you should be able to use the dataset builder in AC to validate this.  There are some unsupported objects in the builder they can be seen on page 48 - in the data integration guide - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_admin_guide_data_integration_guide.pdf

Comment: This answer is false in so many ways. Wave does allow reporting on custom objects. It also doesn't require the data in it to come from Salesforce - it can come from almost any outside data source and be loaded via an API.